# Persist Payment Information Through All States in Angular Web Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, security, cookies

I am building an Angular Web application that processes the payments. (Angular JS 1.x)

I have built backend API to process the payment after Final Confirmation State.

There are total 3 States in Application.

1. State1: User selects due invoices.
2. State2: User provides Payment Information (Credit Card Information)
3. State3: Summary and Confirmation.

A user can go back or refresh the page anytime.

I am persisting selected invoices by storing them in local storage so they remain selected on page refresh or state changes.

I want to persist the Payment(Credit Card) Information **Securely** once user enters them on state2.

**So it remains there even user refresh the page.**

I see two secure ways here:

1. Storing payment(credit card) Information in service/factory object/variable: But this won't persist information while refreshing the page.
2. Storing payment(Credit Card) Information in cookies: But I don't think this is the secure way to do so.

Normally I prefer to store this kind of information in session but here in angular front end I am not able to do so.

Is there any better or proper way in Angular Web application to persist payment(credit card) Information securely.

Answer (score 0):

If the data needs to remain even through a browser refresh, then you have two possibilities. Either you send it up to a server and store it there or save it in the browser local storage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see any way to store on a server and don't think to store payment information into the database as well. I found local storage less secure than cookies.